# Why StringJoiner when we already have StringBuilder?

Tags: java, string, java-8, stringbuilder

I recently encountered with a Java 8 class [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) which adds the String using the delimiters and adds prefix and suffix to it, but I can't understand the need of this class as it also uses [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) at the backend and also performs very simple operation of appending the Strings.

Am I missing something by not actually understanding the real purpose of this class?

Comment: Being simple to implement does not preclude being useful when carried out as a class on its own. Especially when considering *how often* application programmers had to do similar by hand (or via 3rd party library).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`StringJoiner` is very useful, when you need to join Strings in a `Stream`.

As an example, if you have to following List of Strings:

```
final List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar", "Baz");
```

It is much more simpler to use

```
final String collectJoin = strings.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

as it would be with a `StringBuilder`:

```
final String collectBuilder =
    strings.stream().collect(Collector.of(StringBuilder::new,
        (stringBuilder, str) -> stringBuilder.append(str).append(", "),
        StringBuilder::append,
        StringBuilder::toString));
```

**EDIT 6 years later**
As noted in the comments, there are now much simpler solutions like `String.join(", ", strings)`, which were not available back then. But the use case is still the same.

Comment: Note that these two examples are _not_ the same! The first generates the string `"foo, Bar, Baz"`, and the second generates `"foo, Bar, Baz, "`.

Comment: @PaulWagland Yes, that's the extra beauty of the `.joining`. Usually, you *don't* need the last comma...

Comment: @Koshinae agree totally, fixing that in the streaming case also makes the already complicated statement even more complicated!

Comment: `String.join(", ", strings)` is a quicker verrsion for `strings.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "))`

Comment: What about:  `list.stream().map(Util::quote).collect(Collectors.joining(","))` ?

Answer (score 28):

The examples on the [StringJoiner Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) are very good at covering this.  The whole point to to abstract away the choice of seperator from the act of adding entries.  e.g. you can create a joiner, specify the seperator to use and pass it to a library to do the adding of elements or visa versa.

> The String "[George:Sally:Fred]" may be constructed as follows:
>
> ```
> StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(":", "[", "]");
> sj.add("George").add("Sally").add("Fred");
> String desiredString = sj.toString();
> ```
>
> A StringJoiner may be employed to create formatted output from a Stream using Collectors.joining(CharSequence). For example:
>
> ```
> List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
> String commaSeparatedNumbers = numbers.stream()
>     .map(i -> i.toString())
>     .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
> ```

Comment: Peter, have you done any benchmarking on the performance of StringBuilder vs. StringJoiner?  Which one would you prefer from that regard?

Comment: @Simeon I would use String joiner if I want an implicit separator between each thing I append and a string builder if not. It's not about performance but making the desired action clearer.

Answer (score 16):

It may simplify your code in some use cases:

```
List<String> list = // ...;

// with StringBuilder
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("[");
if (!list.isEmpty()) {
    builder.append(list.get(0));
    for (int i = 1, n = list.size(); i < n; i++) {
        builder.append(",").append(list.get(i));
    }
}
builder.append("]");

// with StringJoiner
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]");
for (String element : list) {
    joiner.add(element);
}
```

Comment: It would be great if StringJoiner would have a method receiving a List or Collection and do the iteration + adding each element internally.

Answer (score 13):

`StringJoiner` is a kind of a *Collector*, although it doesn't implement the `Collector` interface. It just behaves as such. Besides you can pass delimiter, prefix and suffix, the `StringJoiner` may be employed to create formatted output from a `Stream` invoking `Collectors.joining(CharSequence)`.

This is especially useful when working with **parallel streams**, because at some point the batches that are being process in parallel will need to be *joined* and this is where the `StringJoiner` takes place.

Comment: Not exactly.  It is a low-level utility component suitable for use from a Collector (joining() does in fact use it), but also suitable outside the world of Streams too.  People write these kinds of loops all the time.

Answer (score 7):

StringJoiner is far simpler than using StringBuilder. A very simple code is like

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(",");
        sj.add("aaa");
        sj.add("bbb");
        sj.add("ccc");
        String result = sj.toString(); //aaa,bbb,ccc
```