# Using Lambda expression to replace chars in string using HashMap

Tags: java, lambda

So i'm working on a project in which I have to convert a String containing greek letters in to a string containing the english representation for this letter. So a greek `α` would become `alpha` and `Α` would become `Alpha`.

I have created a HashMap which has the appropriate conversions from Unicode Character to a normal String.

I have used a simple `For` loop to check if a `Char` in the input `String` is a `Key` in the `HashMap` and if it is then i'll append its replacement using a `StringBuilder`. Here is the code I use to do this:

```
char[] ca = snippet.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : ca) {
            if (GREEK_LETTER_DICT.containsKey(Character.toString(c))) {
                out.append( GREEK_LETTER_DICT.get(Character.toString(c)));
            } else {
                out.append(c);
            }
        }
    return out.toString();
```

This is in a public static method with `String` as input.
The thing I want to know is if it is possible to do the same with a lambda expression? I have already found a couple of solutions replacing a `Character` in `String` but they do not use a `HashMap`/`Dictionary`.

I understand that it is completely useless to just convert this into a lambda expression for the sake of using a lambda expression, but because I have another 7 of these functions shortening my code by almost 60% I would like to see if it is at all possible to do this in "one line" of code. This way i can decrease the number of separate methods I use and get cleaner code.

So far I have found a way to convert a `String` to a `Stream` using:

```
String.chars()
```

Then converting this `IntStream` to a `Stream<Character>` with

```
.mapToObj(ch -> (char) ch)
```

and filtering to see if the `Character` is in the `HashMap` with

```
.filter(ch -> (GREEK_LETTER_DICT.containsKey(ch)))
```

The problem lies in the fact that I am not able to

1. append the original `Character` to the output `String` if it is not in the `HashMap`
2. replace the `Character` with the String in the `HashMap`

So any help on these two points is appreciated. I found out that sometimes I think the wrong way around because instead of seeing if a `Character` in a `String` is equal to a `Character` in a list of options, I should have checked if that list of options returns a positive `index`. So this (PseudeoCode):

`"StringWithOptions".indexOf('characterLiteral')`

instead of this:

`Character.equals("One|of|these")`

Comment: Based on code in question `str.chars().forEach(character -> out.append(GREEK_LETTER_DICT.getOrDefault(Character.toString(c), c)));`

Comment: Well that was fast ;-) Thanks for the reply. with this code is was able to get it to work. I will put it up here. I had to make a few changes to the code.

Comment: @SMA beautiful. I'd advise you to put this into an answer.

Answer (score 4):

How about that:

```
public static String replaceGreekLetters(String snippet) {
    return snippet
            .chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
            .map(c -> GREEK_LETTER_DICT.getOrDefault(c, c.toString()))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Comment: this is better than manipulating a state variable(Stringbuilder), it provides better parallelism :)

Comment: @niceman The filter this is for can be executed in parallel. would you recommend not using the `StringBuilder` then?

Comment: @NathanvanDalen yes I would

Comment: I couldn't get this to work without adding `c.toString()` to the first parameter of the `getOrDefault` also. I think the `mapToObj` should map to `String`.

Comment: @4Castle My initial TS contains an error where `GREEK_LETTER_DICT.containsKey(Character.toString(c))` should be `GREEK_LETTER_DICT.containsKey(c)`, because the HashMap is <Character, String> but I forgot to change that. @xehpuk's code is correct.

Comment: @niceman: well, it’s still using `StringBuilder`s behind the scene and you will need a `snippet` with thousands, if not millions, of characters to get a benefit from parallel processing; it’s even possible that the required merge step will *always* outweigh any parallel benefits…

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
str
    .chars()
    .forEach(
        character -> out.append(
            GREEK_LETTER_DICT.getOrDefault(Character.toString(c), c)
        )
    );
```

Comment: isn't `map` better ? the OP would then not need the StringBuilder at all ?

Comment: This is just an excuse to use streams. Use a normal for each loop if it's going to be stateful.

Answer (score 2):

There are several good solutions using Steams. I like the simpler ones more:

- avoid conversion from char to String
- avoid usage of StringBuffer outside the Stream pipline
- use predefined Collector

```
public class ReplaceGreek {

    private Map<String, String> DICT = new HashMap<>();
    {
        DICT.put("α", "alpha");
    }

    public String replace(final String original) {
        return Arrays.stream(original.split(""))
                .map(c -> DICT.getOrDefault(c, c))
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
}
```

And it even works!

```
public class ReplaceGreekTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ReplaceGreek rg = new ReplaceGreek();
        String greek = "This is greek: α";

        String nogreek = rg.replace(greek);

        assertEquals("This is greek: alpha", nogreek);
    }

}
```

Comment: The OP is using a `Map<Character, String>`. Good solution though!

Comment: But is this Thread Safe? I guess it is because `String` itself is. This is indeed a very elegant solution with just 3 lines of code. A big difference in readability compared to my 10 lines earlier. @4castle: I can easily switch back to `<String, String>` though.

Comment: @NathanvanDalen Yes, it's thread safe. It does very similar things to the other solution.

Comment: You may use `Pattern.compile("").splitAsStream(original)` instead of `Arrays.stream(original.split(""))` to avoid the creation of the temporary array. Still, `original.chars().mapToObj(c -> Character.toString((char)c))` is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

So using the code from [SMA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315228/sma) and [Martin Seeler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522563/why-stringjoiner-when-we-already-have-stringbuilder) I was able to get it to work. The resulting code now returns a `String` with the correct results and passes all my unit tests.

This is the resulting code:

```
    return snippet.chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
            .collect(Collector.of(StringBuilder::new,
                    (stringBuilder, c) -> stringBuilder.append(GREEK_LETTER_DICT.getOrDefault(c,c.toString())),
                    StringBuilder::append,
                    StringBuilder::toString));
```

The Code from [SMA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315228/sma) had one problem where the `HashMap` uses `<Character, String>` and not `<String, String>`. So I had to change the parameters of `#getOrDefault`. Combining this with `.mapToObj(c -> (char) c)` did the trick.

Now lets see if I can change this:

```
(stringBuilder, c) -> stringBuilder.append(GREEK_LETTER_DICT.getOrDefault(c,c.toString())),
                        StringBuilder::append
```

to something like `StringBuilder::append(GREEK_LETTER_DICT.getOrDefault(c,Character.toString(c))`

Comment: …you consider this shorter/simpler than your original loop?