# error: cannot find symbol class StringJoiner in android

Tags: android, apache-commons

I am getting the below error when I use this gradle dependency:

```
 compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'
```

is any way to fix this or it is incompatible with android. Is any others ways to use StringJoiner?

```
error: cannot find symbol class StringJoiner
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The error created when I build the project.

Comment: check in your code, might be some import missing

Comment: i canot build it. In my code i use import java.util.StringJoiner; which is failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your target version is 24. [StringJoiner](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/StringJoiner.html) was introduced starting API 24.

If you support <= API 24, consider using [StringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

To know the difference, please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522563/why-stringjoiner-when-we-already-have-stringbuilder).