# Difference between textfield and console print

Tags: java, swing, textfield

I store data to the array list called `array` and then display the highest number per day using the following functions:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    array
   .stream()
   .collect(

      Collectors.groupingBy(e ->(e.getDate()),

             Collectors.maxBy((e1, e2) -> (int) (e1.getData() - e2. getData()))))

    .forEach((date, sensor) -> 
          System.out.println("" + date + " - " + sensor.map(Sensor:: getData).get()));
          //jTextField1.setText("" + date + " - " + sensor.map(Sensor:: getData).get()));  

}
```

The problem is that when I am using `System.out.println("" + date + " - " + sensor.map(Sensor:: getData).get()));` **->** The whole list of data are printed.
However I want this list to be appeared in the text field in my swing application. And when I am using `jTextField1.setText("" + date + " - " + sensor.map(Sensor:: getData).get()));`  **->** then only one day appears(the last one).

Why it happens?
And how can I print the whole list in the text field.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> then only one day appears(the last one).
>
> Why it happens?

Because you iterate over all the elements and exit the loop at the final element that called `setText`.

You can print fine because all elements append to the output buffer where `setText` will only set the text to the value you give.

You could `collect` the stream to a `List<String>`, and then use a `StringJoiner` with `"\n"`, and end that with a call to `setText`.

Usage details: [Why StringJoiner when we already have StringBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522563/why-stringjoiner-when-we-already-have-stringbuilder#27522845)

(or just use a `StringBulder` and `append` in the `forEach`, and `setText` outside of it)

Comment: Thanks. I used the second suggestion. The only question is: why it does no allow me to use two append commands like this: `builder.append("" + date + " - " + heatDetectorSensor.map(HeatSensor::getCelsius).get())).append("\n");`?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `.forEach()` iterates over the values contained in the stream.

- In the case of the console, each entry is printed in order.
- In the case of the `TextField`, the field's text is set several times in a row, each time overwriting the previous value. That way in the end only the last entry remains.

As a solution, you could:

- `map` the list to a `List<String>`
- `collect` the values with `Collectors.joining("\n")`, obtaining a `String`
- `setText()` of the `TextField` passing the value returned by `collect`