# Spring AOP - ProceedingJoinpoint - MethodSignature Downcast

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

Is there a way to get the MethodSignature from a ProceedingJoinPoint without downcasting?

```
    private String toEventString(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    MethodSignature methodSignature = ((MethodSignature)pjp.getSignature());

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String[] paramNames = methodSignature.getParameterNames();
    Class[] paramTypes = methodSignature.getParameterTypes();

    sb.append(methodSignature.getName()).append('(');

    for(int i = 0; i < paramNames.length; i++) {
        sb
            .append(paramTypes[i].getSimpleName())
            .append(" ")
            .append(paramNames[i]);
        if(i < paramNames.length - 1) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
    }

    return sb.append(" )").toString();

}
```

Comment: Side note: [`StringJoiner`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27522724/1225328) may simplify your code.

Comment: Another side note: I have used AspectJ for a long time. I never really understood the motive for logging variable names and for constructing complicated signature strings if you can just log `thisJoinPoint` or `thisJoinPoint.getSignature()`. It just makes the code slow and cluttered. An aspect is not a replacement for a debugger, especially when used in production. But well, it is a matter of taste. Mine happens to be different. The question is still valid though, which is why I answered it.

Comment: @kriegaex The motive for this is to log all method invocations across a specific layer of the application.  Signature does not provide parameter names, which make the log statements ambiguous.

Comment: If you think about your previous statement for a minute, you will find that it is false. A method signature is uniquely defined by its parameter types, distinguishing it from all other methods of the same name any given class. Parameter names are completely irrelevant for identifying a method, there is no ambiguity. If you say it is eye candy and your brain just finds it easier to read, fine. But ambiguous without parameter names: no.

Comment: Parameters would be ambiguous to the log consumer, which may not have intimate knowledge of the application.  The log consumer shouldn't have to reference my source code to understand the parameters.  If these values are being consumed by an ELK stack or something like that, the parameter name is very important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple question, simple answer: no.

**Update:** Maybe you wonder why you need to cast. Are there other signature types other than method signatures? Oh yes, there are. E.g. if you use `within(SomeClass)` you could encounter any of the following signature types:

- method
- constructor
- class initializer
- field
- advice execution
- catch clause
- lock / unlock (a rather special case, capturing synchronized blocks if aspects are compiled with `-Xjoinpoints:synchronization`)

Here is a little example:

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  private String name;

  public Application(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application = new Application("my app");
    synchronized (application) {
      try {
        application.doSomething("foo", 11, false);
      }
      catch (RuntimeException e) {}
    }
  }

  private void doSomething(String string, int i, boolean b) {
    throw new RuntimeException("oops");
  }
}
```

**Aspect the advice execution of which should be intercepted:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

public aspect MyOtherAspect {
  before() : execution(* main(..)) {}
}
```

**Aspect printing signature types:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Application;

public aspect MyAspect {
  before() : within(Application) || within(MyOtherAspect) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    System.out.println("    " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getClass().getSimpleName());
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
staticinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.Application.<clinit>)
    InitializerSignatureImpl
staticinitialization(de.scrum_master.aspect.MyOtherAspect.<clinit>)
    InitializerSignatureImpl
preinitialization(de.scrum_master.aspect.MyOtherAspect())
    ConstructorSignatureImpl
initialization(de.scrum_master.aspect.MyOtherAspect())
    ConstructorSignatureImpl
execution(de.scrum_master.aspect.MyOtherAspect())
    ConstructorSignatureImpl
adviceexecution(void de.scrum_master.aspect.MyOtherAspect.before())
    AdviceSignatureImpl
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[]))
    MethodSignatureImpl
call(de.scrum_master.app.Application(String))
    ConstructorSignatureImpl
preinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.Application(String))
    ConstructorSignatureImpl
initialization(de.scrum_master.app.Application(String))
    ConstructorSignatureImpl
execution(de.scrum_master.app.Application(String))
    ConstructorSignatureImpl
set(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.name)
    FieldSignatureImpl
lock(lock(Object))
    LockSignatureImpl
call(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething(String, int, boolean))
    MethodSignatureImpl
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething(String, int, boolean))
    MethodSignatureImpl
call(java.lang.RuntimeException(String))
    ConstructorSignatureImpl
handler(catch(RuntimeException))
    CatchClauseSignatureImpl
unlock(unlock(Object))
    UnlockSignatureImpl
```

BTW, each of those `*Impl` classes implements a corresponding signature interface.

Comment: Thanks to my insomnia tonight, I just added some sample code + more explanation. Enjoy! And forgive me for preferring native AspectJ syntax. It is easy to convert to @AspectJ style.

Comment: Very informative, thanks!  I didn't realize there were so many different available pointcuts.  I've only had a need for method level AOP.